# Unresolved external symbol when linking ffmpeg/avcodec with Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, ffmpeg

I'm trying to build ffmpeg/avcodec library with Visual Studio 2015 and it gives me following linking error:

```
allcodecs.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ff_h263_vaapi_hwaccel 
allcodecs.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ff_h263_vdpau_hwaccel
allcodecs.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ff_h263_videotoolbox_hwaccel
...
```

The problem comes from this macro https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavcodec/allcodecs.c#L34

```
#include "config.h"
#include "avcodec.h"
#include "version.h"

...

#define REGISTER_HWACCEL(X, x)                                      \
    {                                                               \
        extern AVHWAccel ff_##x##_hwaccel;                          \
        if (CONFIG_##X##_HWACCEL)                                   \
            av_register_hwaccel(&ff_##x##_hwaccel);                 \
    }

...

void avcodec_register_all(void)
{
    static int initialized;

    if (initialized)
        return;
    initialized = 1;

    /* hardware accelerators */
    REGISTER_HWACCEL(H263_VAAPI,        h263_vaapi);
    REGISTER_HWACCEL(H263_VIDEOTOOLBOX, h263_videotoolbox);
    ...
```

I don't understand why do these methods even get declared when my config has them set to 0

```
#define CONFIG_H263_VAAPI_HWACCEL 0
#define CONFIG_H263_VDPAU_HWACCEL 0
#define CONFIG_H263_VIDEOTOOLBOX_HWACCEL 0
...
```

Btw it builds OK when I use msys/make tooling.

Answer (score 0):

You may be trying to link C code with C++ name mangling.
Try:

```
extern "C"
{
#include <avcodec.h>
#include <avformat.h>
}
```

Comment: I'm not using the library in my code ... I'm trying to build the library itself.